# Want to show 500 images for my e catalogue apps in wp7

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I want to show nearly 500 images serially in my e-catalogue application.

It should be like panorama view, the half of the image appear in the first screen when drag the next half will appear. Like that I have to show 500 jpeg images like a ebook application. Which is the best way?

I have tried it in panorama using selection changed event but it can't load quickly. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You've not posted much code to go on, but it sounds like you're probably loading all of your pictures at the start of the application.  Is that the case?

Comment: I need to add first three or five and using the selection changed event when reach the last image the next image will get loaded and the first image will be removed

Comment: Yes, you do... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I loaded 200 images from a URL and stored in a isolated storage and by a button click event in a panorama view the first 3 pages stream from the isolated storage and i have shown that..using the selection changed event when i select and drag the first image the 4th image is added and first image is removed but it takes a while to do that and when streaming from the iso storage the bitmap image is not fit for the panorama view when i drag the first 5 millimeter content of the page is get inside..thats y i need another view for this

Comment: I loaded 200 images from a URL and stored in a isolated storage and by a button click event in a panorama view the first 3 pages stream from the isolated storage and i have shown that..using the selection changed event when i select and drag the first image the 4th image is added and first image is removed but it takes a while to do that and when streaming from the iso storage the bitmap image is not fit for the panorama view when i drag the first 5 millimeter content of the page is get inside..thats y i need another view for this –

Comment: copying and pasting the same answer all over the page isn't going to help you get a sensible response.  Post some of your code so we can see what you're doing - it's not clear what you're doing, whether you're threading the data access, what your UI is like, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

try load the two first image (1.jpeg and 2.jpeg) and with the event, when you are on 2.jpeg (load another image (3.jpeg))

Comment: Additionally, you can preload 4.jpeg and 5.jpeg in background with ThreadPool if user will switch between images quickly.

Comment: I loaded 200 images from a URL and stored in a isolated storage and by a button click event in a panorama view the first 3 pages stream from the isolated storage and i have shown that..using the selection changed event when i select and drag the first image the 4th image is added and first image is removed but it takes a while to do that and when streaming from the iso storage the bitmap image is not fit for the panorama view when i drag the first 5 millimeter content of the page is get inside..thats y i need another view for this –

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using virtual paging an article with sample project can be found here

http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/virtual-paging-in-silverlight